# Add "ID" in onClick event of the PHP form dynamically

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to add an ID in the onClick event of the form input button but I am unable to figure out how it will take this dynamically every time when ID changes. For example:

```
<form>
    <?php $gid= isset($_GET['gid']) ? $_GET['gid'] : 0;
                 $keyword= isset($_GET['keyword']) ? $_GET['keyword'] : '';
                 echo '<input type="hidden" name="gid" value='.$gid.'>';
                 echo"$gid";
    
                 echo '<input type="hidden" name="keyword" value='.$keyword.'>';?>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="p-pom-button" id="lp-pom-button-720" onclick="window.location.href='new.php?gid=xxxxxxx'"; />
</form>
```

The ID is coming from the URL of the website, say, [www.example.com/index.php?gid=123](http://www.example.com/index.php?gid=123). Here, index.php has the above code where it should come in onClick event automatically and once the user clicks, it will take the user to [www.example.com/new.php?gid=123](http://www.example.com/new.php?gid=123)

Comment: The onclick doesn't seem to make sense. None of the other form fields will be submitted if you use that. You've already got the ID in a hidden field. If you've got that within a form the it would be submitted anyway. Maybe you need to understand how forms work a bit better

Answer (score 2):

Assuming from above that you are getting the ID value from `$_GET['gid']`, you can just print it in the input element with php tags as below,

```
<form>
    <?php $gid= isset($_GET['gid']) ? $_GET['gid'] : 0;
                 $keyword= isset($_GET['keyword']) ? $_GET['keyword'] : '';
                 echo '<input type="hidden" name="gid" value='.$gid.'>';
                 echo"$gid";
    
                 echo '<input type="hidden" name="keyword" value='.$keyword.'>';?>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="p-pom-button" id="lp-pom-button-720" onclick="window.location.href='new.php?gclid=<?php echo $gid; ?>'"; />
</form>
```